# Python String Accumulator

Tags: python, string, accumulate

I am trying to write a code that returns a user input as the following example-

User input:- hello

Return: H-Ee-Lll-Llll-Ooooo

Basically,  I want each letter increased by 1, a dash between each letter, and the first letter being capital between each dash.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hello Johnathan, welcome to StackOverflow. The best way to get answers to your queries is to present what you've already tried, share code snippets and error messages and ask exact questions specific to your query! Please feel free to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can control that the input will always be lowercase, the answer from @Sup is smaller.

In case you need to worry about different cases, I suggest this one that is a bit easier to read/understand if you don't have much experience with list comprehension:

```
def string_acumulator(input: str):
    output = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(input):
        repetition = i+1
        word = letter * repetition
        output.append(word.capitalize())
    return '-'.join(output)

print(string_acumulator('HELLO'))
>>> H-Ee-Lll-Llll-Ooooo
print(string_acumulator('hello'))
>>> H-Ee-Lll-Llll-Ooooo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list` comprehension:

```
input = "hello"
print('-'.join([i.upper()+i*n for n,i in enumerate(input)]))
```